# This piece of code from w3schools is not working properly?

Tags: php

It seems to be working [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_special) but when I just copy and paste the code into notepad and try to run in browser I get an extra `>` character before "name" like this.

php 4.3.0

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
   else
     {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
       {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
       }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
     {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
   else
     {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
     if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
       {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
       }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["website"]))
     {$website = "";}
   else
     {
     $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website))
       {
       $websiteErr = "Invalid URL";
       }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
     {$comment = "";}
   else
     {$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
     {$genderErr = "Gender is required";}
   else
     {$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);}
}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
   <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="email"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Website:</label> <input type="text" name="website"> <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <label>Comment:</label> <input type="text" name="comment">
   <br><br>
   <label>Gender:</label>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>
```

Comment: Show us the code. The image is not so helpful.

Comment: the code is from link from w3school just look at that link

Comment: Also, [I generally shy away from w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: Is it being run in an Apache server? Or did you open it in the browser pointing to the file?

Comment: yes in apache on my local machine

Comment: You have to use PHP server and run w3school code there.

Comment: @munish That `">` is coming before `Name` obviously. Try using single quotes like this instead `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` or just use `action=""` that does the same thing as submitting to self. My test turned out fine on my end, leaving your code "as is".

Comment: @munish Actually, I meant `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` with the added `echo`

Answer (score 1):

> but when i just copy paste the code into notepad and try to run in
>   browser.i get an extra `">" character before name like this.

You cannot just paste the code in Notepad and save. Then, run the file directly from browser. PHP does not work that way. You need proper web server such as Apache and IIS, then have PHP installed and configure to work with those web server.

Assuming that you run it with web server and you still have this problem. The chance is that you have not properly configure PHP. You can test if PHP works by try a simple code first.

```
<?php echo "Is PHP working?"; ?>
```

or

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: this runs`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`  fine i have apache2 installed and confiured for php 4.3.0 and php also installed

Comment: @munish, try to "View Source" from your browser to see whether you see PHP code in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up an Apache server.

1. [download](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and install XAMPP
2. put that code in C://xampp/htdocs name it `example.php`
3. run the apache server from the xampp dashboard
4. in your browser goto `localhost/example.php`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use .html extension while saving this code. It should go .php code also you need to run a code using php server like WAMP, XAMP, etc.

I recommend WAMP. It is easy.
1.  So, Download WAMP and install.
2. Save your .php file inside the www directory inside wamp ( where you installed.)
3. go to your browser.
4. type localhost
5. click the file you've saved recently from the list.
6. It works then after.

Answer (score 0):

You're not outputting anything here:

`action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"`

Change that to: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"`

Or if [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is enabled: `action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"`.

Comment: Strangely enough, using `<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>` worked on my hosted server, with FF 24; funny that. However, you stand at being right on this. May very well be just that, in adding/using `echo`. I suggested to the OP to use `action=""` which rounds up to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't use the escape character which resulted in this error. You can alternatively use the single quote too.

Use this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

OR use an escape character:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER[\"PHP_SELF\"];?>">
```